# Почему в сафари круг становится овалом?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть вот такой круг, при медиа запросе на max-width для него он уменьшается как положено, но становится овалом. Почему так?

[image: Вот такой должен быть]

[image: Вот такой выходит]

```
&__value-circle {
        width: 380px;
        height: 380px;
        border: 4px solid #F9E214;
        border-radius: 50%;
        aspect-ratio: 1/1;
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 12px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;

        @include SmallTablet {
            max-width: 380px;
            max-height: 380px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        &__wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 2px solid #F9E214;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        &__number {
            font-size: 64px;
            font-weight: 500;
            color: #4E4E4E;

            @include SmallTablet {
                font-size: 32px;
            }
        }
    }

<div class="calculator__content__value-circle">
     <div class="calculator__content__value-circle__wrapper">
         <span class="calculator__content__value-circle__number"
                                        id="calcResult">0€</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Может потому что `width: 100%; height: 100%;` ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ZEMJLgw а вот это нормально отображается в сафари ?